# Run as Administrator Issue when using Bins from 1UpIndustries

Tags: windows, taskbar

I use an addon called Bins by 1UpIndustries to group my taskbar items. If I turn off bins my shortcuts run as an administrator as I have configured them to do with no problems. However whenever I turn on Bins, and group up my taskbar items the programs no longer run as administrator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I figured this out on my own. It occurred to me that the taskbar shortcuts grouped by Bins weren't being launched directly, but instead by the Bins application so I went ahead and set the Bins application to run as administrator by default, and boom all shortcuts now run as administrator. Hope this helps someone.